# UITableViewCell with labels that dynamically appear/hide using Auto Layout

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7, autolayout

I have a UITableViewCell defined in a XIB with auto-layout enabled. It contains multiple UILabels, one of which often runs to more than one line. I am able to appropriately adjust the height of the cell based on its content. The layout is similar to the example below:

[image: UITableViewCell Example 1]

What I would like to now implement is an additional UILabel that may not be present at initial render time, but is then populated when a user presses the action button.

[image: UITableViewCell Example 2]

What is the best way to accomplish this using auto layout?

**UPDATE**:

I am attempting to hide/show the dynamic label by adding/removing a constraint with height = 0, but am experiencing issues related to placement/size of the other labels. I have provided an example project showing these issues here: https://github.com/markdorison/AutoLayoutExample

Answer (score 0):

You can animated the constraint by creating an outlet to it and just changing the constant followed by a call to `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` - all within an animation block